# on mouseover show only current card hover effect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxtjs

On mouseover show only current card hover effect.
At the moment if my mouse goes to over card then it shows every card effect.

How is this possible in Vue Nuxtjs?

What Im trying to achieve is this. If mouse goes on then it would start playing gif and if mouse goes off then it shows static image.

My code:

```
<div v-b-hover="handleHover" class="team-img">
  <img
    v-if="isHovered"
    :srcset="member.node.teamMemberFields.imageGif"
  />
  <img v-else :srcset="member.node.teamMemberFields.image.srcSet" />
</div>
```

Script code:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isHovered: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleHover(hovered) {
      this.isHovered = hovered
    },
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` events.
With Vue syntax it can be written `v-on:mouseover` or `@mouseover`.

```html
<div @mouseover="isHovered = true" @mouseleave="isHovered = false" class="team-img">
  <img
    v-show="isHovered"
    :srcset="member.node.teamMemberFields.imageGif"
  />
  <img v-show="!isHovered" :srcset="member.node.teamMemberFields.image.srcSet" />
</div>
```

Also, I suggest to use `v-show` instead of `v-if` as it will be much more performant in this case because the element may be shown / hide multiple times at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`index`** of **`v-for`** to make a change to the current hovering item. In this example, the color of only one hovered item can be changed to **`red`**.

```html
<template>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item">
    <h3
      @mouseover="{ isHovered = true; indexHover = index; }"
      @mouseleave="isHovered = false"
      :style="isHovered && indexHover == index ? 'color:red' : ''"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </h3>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
      isHovered: false,
      indexHover: null,
    };
  },
}
</script>
```